# How does sunburst work?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I'm playing around with [Auriel's bow](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Auriel%27s_Bow) and the sunburst shot and I have a few questions about its effectiveness.

- Can it strike a target multiple times?
- How much damage does it do?
- Does it cause friendly fire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes. Sunburst shots from Sunhallowed Elven Arrow will create a small AoE (area of effect) of blast upon impact and mainly effective again undeads and vampires.
2. Base damage:

   `16(elven arrow) + 20(sun damage) + 13(Auriel's Bow) = 49`

   Note: This is not including Archery perks (Overdraw etc.) and armor enchantments. Also 3x damage for sun damage if used on undead and vampires (total base damage 89).
3. Yes.

Comment: oh nice, so bow damage boosts sunburst, that's good to know.